# How would I test whether the average of multidimensional data is different

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have data points in two dimensions. Each point has associated errors in both dimensions (see figure). I would like to test whether the data are different from each other. So e.g., is orange different from green? I could do individual tests along each axis, but it would be great if a test existed that would allow me to test both dimensions at once.
I hope this makes sense. thank you!

[image]

Comment: You might be looking after MANOVA, the multivariate analysis of variance.

Comment: Is it really just one point for each colour? Or, are there several points for each colour, and you've calculated the mean and error?

Comment: @rw2, it is multiple points with calculated mean and error

Comment: Look through the tag [tag:hotelling-t2].